# Sorting an arraylist in Java language

Tags: java, inputbox

I have an arraylist set up. I have input instuctions set up too, so that the user can enter one string, then one integer, then one string (the first name, the age, and the last name).

I need to sort the arraylist by the last name. The code I have entered so far is all under the main method:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Name Name[] = new Name[50];
int count = 0;

for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
  NewName[i] = new Name();

//ADD NEW TO ARRAYLIST NAME
String FName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("first name");
int age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("age"));
String LName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("last name");
          NewName[count] = new Name(FName, age, LName);
count = count++;
}

//ITEMS SORT BY LAST NAME
//CODE FOR SORT GOES HERE
```

Comment: There is convention to name variables from small letter in java.

Comment: You are using an array of Name objects, not actually using an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Sorting depends on the implementation of the `Name` object. I can only hint you about `Arrays.sort`, `Collections.sort`, and `Comparator`.

Comment: just as a side note:
count = count++; will increase count by... 0, zero, nil, nought.
count = ++count; would increase count by 1.
count++; would increase count by 1.
count += 1; would increase count by 1.

Comment: So this is not an arraylist? It's just an array?

I have tried to use:-
Arrays.sort(NewName);
Collections.sort(NewName);

And both do not work, the compiler fails...

Comment: @Computeristic
That's because line 2 should be: "Name[] NewName = new Name[50];"
And yes: it's an Array, not an ArrayList.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but it still doesn't work when I enter Arrays.sort(NewName); OR Collections.sort(NewName);...So what do you think is the problem? And how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: read the spec for Arrays.sort - your Names either needs to implement the Comparable interface (saugata's answer) or you need to provide a Comparator (again, saugata's answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), [Arrays.sort](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T[],%20java.util.Comparator%29) and [Collections.sort](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

```
import java.util.Arrays;


class Name implements Comparable<Name> {

    private String lastName;
    //Other fields

    public Name(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int compareTo(Name o) {
        //Null checks etc
        return lastName.compareTo(o.lastName);
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    //Getter and setter methods
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name[] arr = new Name[]{new Name("AAC"), new Name("AAD"), new Name("AAA"),new Name("ABC"), new Name("AADDE")};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for(Name nm:arr){
            System.out.println(nm.getLastName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The null checks are actually not required here (or when instanceof is used).

Comment: @Helper Method Are you referring to the compareTo method? Actually it is, the parameter could be null.

Comment: @sauguta Sry, you're right, I thought String's compareTo() method would do the null check.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't meant to be offensive but I would suggest you learn the basics before you move on to Swing.

Comment: I think Helper is suggesting arrays are the basics.  I'd tend to agree.